# Gazebo depth sensor not working properly in RViz?

Tags: gazebo, kinect, rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So im busy setting up a proper simulation environment for my robot. During the process i added depth sensors in the URDF file of the robot and images come out great. Though pointclouds show me planes instead of points. So there is a problem somewhere.

To verify it was my problem only i opened up the turtlebot in gazebo and rviz and it shows me the same thing as for the robot i'm working on. So it is a problem for me in general, but I've no idea what it can be. Maybe i've failed to install an important part?

Anyone has an idea? Thanks in advance

For info, im on 14.04 and running Indigo

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239833/gazebo-depth-sensor-not-working-properly-in-rviz?/) by [jonathan123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27543/jonathan123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jonathan123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27543/jonathan123/) on 2016-07-20**:
I'm trying to reinstall ROS, maybe that will help

EDIT: that didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem seems to be I'm running Ubuntu as a virtual machine, which doesn't give gazebo enough juice or something. So if anyone runs into this problem, stop using a VM.

---

Originally posted by [jonathan123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27543/jonathan123/) with karma: 16 on 2016-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0